# Locally working web-app throws VerifyError on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scala, gwt

my web-app based on GWT uses scala-compiler.jar (2.10.3) on its server-side to provide on the fly compiling and executing of Scala code which a user inputs in his/her browser.

It's working fine locally uder GAE SDK 1.8.4 -- when I call service method and pass some trivial script it compiles, executes and logs the resulting string "Hello, Adeal!":

```
final Object o = AdalModuleEval.eval("class C { override def toString = \"Hello, Adeal!\" }; new C()");
log.warning(o.toString());
```

---

But after deploying to Google App Engine server the same code throws me:

```
exception: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack in method sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass()Ljava/lang/reflect/Type; at offset 1
```

Full stack trace you can see [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qFxWibbNayg6QQHAaHZS2rOJ1fDTo-He7_SZVQtENWc/edit?usp=sharing)

It's really disappointing and I'd very appreciate any suggestions about how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved that or this below is not your case, but for me it was a method catching exceptions like this:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (ServiceException | IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Once I put a single `Exception` in every `catch` everything worked properly